# increment alphanumeric string where alphabet position in a string is keeps changing

Tags: vb.net

I need to save Multiple(about 20-25) serial number of the specimen in my application. Sometimes serial number will be alphanumeric but will be sequential. I need a way out to increment alphanumeric serial numbers based on the first serial number entered.
My main problem is alphabet position and alphabet count keeps changing. Example : 10MG2015  20562MG0 MGX02526 etc etc
I tried but mine works when Alphabet are in starting position and when there are known number of alphabets. Here is my try

```
Dim intValue as integer
Dim serialno as string
Dim serialno1 as string
For i =0 to 20
Serialno1 = serialno.Substring(3)
Int32.TryParse(Serialno1, intValue)
intValue = intValue + 1
checkedox1.items.add(serialno.Substring(0,3) + intValue.ToString("D3"))
NEXT
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

edit 1
Clarity : I want to increment alphanumeric string. Example : If first entered one is 10MG2015 then I should increment to 10MG2016, 10MG2017, 10MG2018, 10MG2019 and so on... For 20562MG0 it will be 20562MG1, 20562MG2 20562MG3 and so on...

Comment: These *serial numbers* seem to be composed of 8 *elements*. How should  `20562MG0` increment after 20 iterations? `20562MG19` (adding one element to the series)? Something else?

Comment: It will be sequentially increment.. example : 20562MG20, 20562MG21, 20562MG22 and so on..

Answer (score 0):

```
Function FindSequenceNumber(SerialNumber As String) As Integer
    'Look for at least four digits in a row, and capture all the digits
    Dim sequenceExpr As New Regex("([0-9]{4,11})")

    Dim result As Integer = -1
    Dim m As Match = sequenceExpr.Match(SerialNumber)

    If m.Success AndAlso Integer.TryParse(m.Groups(1).Value, result) Then
        Return result
    Else
       'Throw exception, return -1, etc
    End If
End Function
```

See it here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/gO2nue

Note: the integer type doesn't preserve leading zeros. You may find it better to return a tuple with either the length of the original string, so you can pad zeros to the left if needed to match the original formatting.

Or maybe this:

```
Function IncrementSerial(SerialNumber As String) As String
    'Look for at least four digits in a row, and capture all the digits
    Dim sequenceExpr As New Regex("([0-9]{4,11})")
    Dim m As Match = sequenceExpr.Match(SerialNumber)

    If Not m.Success Then Throw New Exception("No sequence number found")

    Dim c = m.Groups(1).Captures(0) 
    Dim seq = (Integer.Parse(c.Value) + 1).ToString()
    If seq.Length < c.Value.Length Then
        seq = seq.PadLeft(c.Value.Length, "0"c)
    End If

    Dim result As String = ""
    If c.Index > 0 Then result & = SerialNumber.Substring(0, c.Index)
    result &= seq
    If c.Index + seq.Length < SerialNumber.Length Then result &= SerialNumber.SubString(c.Index + seq.Length)
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: The integer type will only take nine 9s, not the eleven possible with that regex. Just in case someone uses it and wonders why they're getting 0 from the TryParse.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But sorry If i was not clear in my question. I want to increment alphanumeric string. Example :  If first entered one is 10MG2015 then I should increment to 10MG2016, 10MG2017, 10MG2018, 10MG2019 and so on...  For 20562MG0 it will be 20562MG1, 20562MG2 20562MG3 and so on...

Comment: `(?<=\D)\d+$` (it looks like it always increment the last numeric part. IMO, the *rule* is only partially defined, though).